# Ionic 6 with Angular doesn't call Api (.net core 5) when run on Real Android Device

Tags: android, angular, api, ionic-framework, .net-core

I'm building an android app using Angular and Ionic.
My problem is the following, on the real device I can't call the API of the backend built with .Net Core 5. In the simulator it works, on the browser it works.

The Error only on real Android Device:

[image]

My Go Rest code to works every api:

```
goRest(): Promise<unknown> {
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.httpClient.get<any>('https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users')
    .subscribe(users => {
      console.log('goRest getted: ', users);
      resolve(users);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Error goRest: ', err);
      reject(false);
    });
});
return promise;
```

}

The strange thing is that if I first call the go rest service before each API, in this case my API of my backend on the real device also works.
If I remove the Go Rest call from the code instead, my APIs no longer work either, it seems that they are dependent on Go Rest.

My backend code (.Net Core 5)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(); // Make sure you call this previous to AddMvc
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyOrigin();
        }));


        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApp", Version = "v1" });
        }); 
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApp v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Why? Maybe SSL certificates? In this case how do I insert them into the Ionic / Angular code?

Basically my application calls the APIs correctly only if first of all, in the component app I call Go Rest, in doing so the APIs of my backend also work, I cannot understand how to solve. I have to remove Go Rest of course.

Last things:

My network_security_config xml

```
 <network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```